# Styling Sylverlight Telerik Radupload

Tags: silverlight, telerik, styling, radupload

At the moment I'm using Silverlight RadControls from Telerik. In my site I've implemented the RadUpload control. Because the control is not styled the way I want, I'm restyling it for my site. The way I'm doing this is as follows: Right click on xRadUpload > Edit Template > Edit a Copy. After doing this I'm able to style almost everything, except for one thing. 
During runtime of the Silverlight application, the xRadUpload enables users to upload files. Those files that are selected using the browse button, show up in the application in several bars. I want to restyle those specific bars.
The problem is, I can't find those bars using Expression Blend. 
I've already looked at the Telerik help documentation. It says that if you want to restyle the control you need to edit the following control templates: RadUpload and UploadItem. 
After reading this I think I need to edit UploadItem, but I cannot find it, while my application works correctly. Has anyone encountered this problem before, who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, for the solution go to http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/upload/xradupload-styling-problem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Telerik has listed the items that are required](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/required_elements.html) in the UploadItem control. If you want to get the control template you can open the Telerik dll in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and in Reflector look in the Resources folder for the dll. You should see the generic.xaml in there and you can double click it to open the file. In that file you should see the control templates.

Comment: I get your point. Unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for. The thing I want is to edit the controls in Expression Blend by right clicking it > edit template > edit a copy/current. In the Scrollviewer there is ItemsPresenter. I want to edit the style of the ItemsPresenter, but I can't find how. I'm unable to edit the template by right clicking it. At the moment I'm able to style everything except for that one. 

Handy tool by the way: Reflector, I'm sure I will use it in the present to solve other problems.

Comment: You can still edit it in blend, you just need to copy the control template using Reflector. Take the xaml and paste it into a style and then use Blend to edit it.

Comment: Bryant, I really appreciate your help. But I just can't figure it out. I tried all kind of things. I tried to copy the RadUploadItem style from upload.xaml by using Reflector. After copying I've pasted it in my main xaml file. After that I tried to set that style for <ItemsPresenter/>. But for some reason it does not work.

Sorry for being such a noob, but this Telerik stuff is new to me, although it is really awesome. Can you please be more specific, step by step? From Which .xaml file do I need to copy? Where do I have to paste it? Etc.